# Email sent but not recieved, I'm using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer v^6.4.17 and I'm having trouble getting it to send emails. I do not get the issue cause in the console, it is showing that the emails has been sent. But when I go to client side and check inbox, I don't see the email.

```js
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: 'www.example.com',
    host: '******************',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
      user: ''sender@email.com'', 
      pass: '**********', 
    },
  });

  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'sender@email.com',
    to: "reciever@email.com",
    subject: "Hi",
    text: "Hello world!",
    html: '<h1>2021</h1>',
  });
```

What I'm I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable the less secure app in your Gmail account.
[enable your Gmail account less secure app](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Also, make sure to check email in spam emails.

Comment: I'm using custom email and my app is using tls/ssl email configs. Does this solution apply?

Comment: Something happened to my when i run the nodemailer script in sandbox with nodemailer temp account, email was successfully send but i had not received any email even in spam email but with person email its work.  I mostly used PHP mailer to send email from server side in node js actually i created an api in php and call the api from node js server.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this -

```
var mailOptions = {
 from: "----------",
 to: "-------",
 subject: "------------",
 text: "------------",
 html: "-----------"
};
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
 if (error) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log("Cannot connect to SMTP server right now");
 } else {
    console.log("Success" + response);
 }
});
```